# GAE unable to look up SRV record for mongodb atlas instance

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an instance of mongodb running on Atlas and a Spring Boot application running on GAE trying to access this database. I have no problem running it locally but when running on GAE I see this error in the logs.

```
com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up SRV record for host xyz-abc-delta-james.gcp.mongodb.net
```

This is my spring boot configuration for mongodb

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy=org.springframework.data.mapping.model.CamelCaseAbbreviatingFieldNamingStrategy
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@xyz-abc-delta-james.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

I tried to find something in the GAE docs but there is no trace of this kind of error.

```
Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up SRV record for host xyz-abc-delta-james.gcp.mongodb.net
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:109)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:692)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:654)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:624)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:818)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anyone come across such a thing? Could this be a network restriction by GAE?

Thanks!

**NB**: I have already posted this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/934687/google-appengine-unable-to-look-up-srv-record) but didn't get any responses.

Comment: Which `mongo-java-driver` version are you using ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*I've found a solution:*

You have to unlock the default outgoing TCP port (the default for MongoDB Atlas is `27017`) in your Google Cloud Console.

More precisely: in the section *Network >> VPC Network >> Firewall* just add a [new rule for mongo traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX1cH.png).

Comment: This solves problem of connecting to mongo, but not the issue with SRV.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently GAE doesn't support the latest (3.6x and up version) format of the mogodb uri, everything worked seamlessly after I switched to the legacy (3.4x and up version) of the uri representation which is quite long.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<user>:<password>@xyz-abc-delta-james.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-bar-shard-00-01-tlxzf.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,foo-bar-shard-00-02-tlxzf.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=foo-bar-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

Since Spring boot has an internal dependency on the 3.6x version, I had to manually add a mongodb dependency for the 3.4 version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had not allowed external traffic from my app through the port I exposed. Therefore, the app's request to mongo cluster (or any other external service) were being blocked by my VPS firewall.

My service configuration had the following snippet:

```
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30100
```

Since I was running a one node cluster in an ubuntu-flavored VPS, all I had to do to allow both outgoing and incoming traffic to the app through its port was to configure ufw like so:

```
sudo ufw allow 30100
```

And my app was able to connect to the external mongo cluster using both the mongo+svr format and the legacy format.