# Kubernetes doesn't recognise SRV type URIs

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube

Does anyone know if there is a specific way to configure Kubernetes to allow resolution of SRV type URLs (to internet services) from within pods?

Recently had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820151/minikube-kubernets-pod-cant-connect-to-mongodb-atlas/61853372#61853372) preventing me from connecting to MongoDB Atlas. Found the cause to be the use of SRV type URI for connection, was fixed after using legacy URI for connection [(link to description)](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-3-6-here-to-SRV-you-with-easier-replica-set-connections?jmp=fcb&utm_source=4244&utm_medium=FBPAGE&utm_term=4&linkId=50841309).

Is there some configuration required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the images like Alpine does not support the srv strings. Instead if you want to make it run either use the standard connection string or use the images to make your container which have minimum libraries to support the srv string.

Comment: Thank you! :D yes im using Alpine so that makes perfect sense, will keep as is for now to save me switching to another image, but nice to finally know what the problem is.