# Unable to lookup SRV record for host with DataGrip

Tags: mongodb, datagrip

I am switching over to using SRV to connect to a mongo DB and I am not able to connect to it due to the following exception (listed below)

The format of the connection string was changed to the following:

```
mongodb+srv://camdbn2a.paychex.com/?authMechanism=PLAIN&ssl=false&connectTimeoutMS=30000&maxIdleTimeMS=600000
```

I am seeing the following when testing the connection.

```
Keep-alive query failed

DBMS: Mongo DB Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.14, JDBC4.2) Effective version: UNKNOWN (ver. 0.0) Ping: 10 sec, 519 ms (keep-alive query results in error)  com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, srvResolutionException=com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up SRV record for host camdbn2a.paychex.com, servers=[].
```

The following is in the idea.log

```
2022-05-09 13:27:57,498 [7906644]   INFO - .DatabaseConnectionEstablisher - Connecting to: mongodb+srv://camdbn2a.paychex.com/?authMechanism=PLAIN&ssl=false&connectTimeoutMS=30000&maxIdleTimeMS=600000

2022-05-09 13:27:57,876 [7907022]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - May 09, 2022 5:27:57 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J

2022-05-09 13:27:57,877 [7907023]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the 'org.mongodb.driver' component

2022-05-09 13:27:58,504 [7907650]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver 1.14

2022-05-09 13:27:58,504 [7907650]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -

2022-05-09 13:28:08,554 [7917700]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - getDatabaseProductName: Mongo DB

2022-05-09 13:28:43,618 [7952764]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - DBMS detection failed

2022-05-09 13:28:43,619 [7952765]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.sql.SQLException: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, srvResolutionException=com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up SRV record for host camdbn2a.paychex.com, servers=[]

2022-05-09 13:28:43,619 [7952765]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.dbschema.mongo.mongosh.MongoshScriptEngine.execute(MongoshScriptEngine.java:67)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,620 [7952766]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.dbschema.mongo.MongoPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MongoPreparedStatement.java:56)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,620 [7952766]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.dbschema.mongo.MongoPreparedStatement.execute(MongoPreparedStatement.java:62)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,620 [7952766]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.dbschema.mongo.MongoPreparedStatement.execute(MongoPreparedStatement.java:480)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,620 [7952766]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil$4.consume(JdbcNativeUtil.java:231)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,621 [7952767]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil$4.consume(JdbcNativeUtil.java:228)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,621 [7952767]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.prepared(JdbcNativeUtil.java:247)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,621 [7952767]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.consume(JdbcNativeUtil.java:228)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,621 [7952767]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.getString(JdbcNativeUtil.java:200)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,621 [7952767]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.getString(JdbcNativeUtil.java:194)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,622 [7952768]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.MongoJdbcHelper.create(MongoJdbcHelper.java:123)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,622 [7952768]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.MongoJdbcHelper.detect(MongoJdbcHelper.java:113)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,622 [7952768]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.detectImpl(JdbcNativeUtil.java:182)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,622 [7952768]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.detectImpl(JdbcNativeUtil.java:169)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,623 [7952769]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcNativeUtil.detect(JdbcNativeUtil.java:129)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,623 [7952769]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:57)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,623 [7952769]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,623 [7952769]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,624 [7952770]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,624 [7952770]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,624 [7952770]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,624 [7952770]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,625 [7952771]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,625 [7952771]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,625 [7952771]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,625 [7952771]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,626 [7952772]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,626 [7952772]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,626 [7952772]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,626 [7952772]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,626 [7952772]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,627 [7952773]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,627 [7952773]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,627 [7952773]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, srvResolutionException=com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Unable to look up SRV record for host camdbn2a.paychex.com, servers=[]

2022-05-09 13:28:43,628 [7952774]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:180)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,628 [7952774]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.getDescription(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:50)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,630 [7952776]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:144)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,631 [7952777]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:101)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,631 [7952777]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:291)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,632 [7952778]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:183)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,632 [7952778]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:195)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,632 [7952778]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:164)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,632 [7952778]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:159)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,633 [7952779]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:149)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,633 [7952779]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider$runCommandWithCheck$1$1.invoke(JavaServiceProvider.kt:43)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,633 [7952779]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider$runCommandWithCheck$1$1.invoke(JavaServiceProvider.kt:39)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,633 [7952779]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.Right.map(Either.kt:23)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,634 [7952780]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider$runCommandWithCheck$1.invoke(JavaServiceProvider.kt:39)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,634 [7952780]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider$runCommandWithCheck$1.invoke(JavaServiceProvider.kt:38)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,634 [7952780]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider.promise(JavaServiceProvider.kt:579)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,634 [7952780]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.service.JavaServiceProvider.runCommandWithCheck(JavaServiceProvider.kt:38)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,635 [7952781]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MHBase.invokeHandle(HostMethodDesc.java:331)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,635 [7952781]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostCodeCache$1.executeImpl(GuestToHostCodeCache.java:96)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,635 [7952781]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostRootNode.execute(GuestToHostRootNode.java:80)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,635 [7952781]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,636 [7952782]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultRuntimeAccessor$DefaultRuntimeSupport.callInlined(DefaultRuntimeAccessor.java:160)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,636 [7952782]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.GuestToHostRootNode.guestToHostCall(GuestToHostRootNode.java:102)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,636 [7952782]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MHBase.invokeGuestToHost(HostMethodDesc.java:362)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,636 [7952782]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doInvoke(HostExecuteNode.java:871)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,637 [7952783]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doFixed(HostExecuteNode.java:137)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,637 [7952783]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:143)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,637 [7952783]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.execute(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:96)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,637 [7952783]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObject.invokeMember(HostObject.java:451)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,637 [7952783]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObjectGen$InteropLibraryExports$Cached.invokeMemberNode_AndSpecialize(HostObjectGen.java:2695)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,638 [7952784]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObjectGen$InteropLibraryExports$Cached.invokeMember(HostObjectGen.java:2677)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,638 [7952784]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.InteropLibraryGen$CachedDispatch.invokeMember(InteropLibraryGen.java:8134)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,638 [7952784]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode$ForeignInvokeNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:1496)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,638 [7952784]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode.executeAndSpecialize(JSFunctionCallNode.java:303)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,638 [7952784]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:248)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,639 [7952785]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode$InvokeNode.execute(JSFunctionCallNode.java:732)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,639 [7952785]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.executeGeneric(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:99)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,639 [7952785]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.executeGeneric(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:47)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,640 [7952786]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -

2022-05-09 13:28:43,640 [7952786]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultBlockNode.executeGeneric(DefaultBlockNode.java:65)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,640 [7952786]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.execute(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:79)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,640 [7952786]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.ReturnNode$TerminalPositionReturnNode.execute(ReturnNode.java:165)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,641 [7952787]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.executeGeneric(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:99)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,641 [7952787]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.executeGeneric(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:47)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,642 [7952788]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultBlockNode.executeGeneric(DefaultBlockNode.java:65)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,642 [7952788]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.execute(AbstractGeneratorBlockNode.java:79)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,642 [7952788]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.FunctionBodyNode.execute(FunctionBodyNode.java:73)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,643 [7952789]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AsyncFunctionBodyNode$AsyncFunctionRootNode.executeInRealm(AsyncFunctionBodyNode.java:140)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,643 [7952789]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.JavaScriptRealmBoundaryRootNode.execute(JavaScriptRealmBoundaryRootNode.java:92)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,643 [7952789]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,643 [7952789]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultIndirectCallNode.call(DefaultIndirectCallNode.java:53)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,643 [7952789]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.InternalCallNode.indirectCall(InternalCallNode.java:76)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,644 [7952790]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.InternalCallNodeGen.execute(InternalCallNodeGen.java:45)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,644 [7952790]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AwaitResumeNode.execute(AwaitResumeNode.java:69)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,644 [7952790]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.control.AwaitNode$AwaitSettledRootNode.execute(AwaitNode.java:342)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,644 [7952790]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,645 [7952791]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultIndirectCallNode.call(DefaultIndirectCallNode.java:53)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,645 [7952791]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode$GenericJSFunctionCacheNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:1630)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,645 [7952791]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.function.JSFunctionCallNode.executeCall(JSFunctionCallNode.java:244)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,646 [7952792]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.nodes.promise.PromiseReactionJobNode$PromiseReactionJobRootNode.execute(PromiseReactionJobNode.java:145)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,647 [7952793]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,647 [7952793]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.call(DefaultCallTarget.java:102)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,647 [7952793]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.builtins.JSFunction.call(JSFunction.java:300)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,648 [7952794]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.JSAgent.processAllPromises(JSAgent.java:208)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,648 [7952794]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.lang.JavaScriptLanguage.interopBoundaryExit(JavaScriptLanguage.java:519)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,648 [7952794]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.objects.JSObject.invokeMember(JSObject.java:244)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,648 [7952794]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.js.runtime.objects.JSObjectGen$InteropLibraryExports$Cached.invokeMember(JSObjectGen.java:400)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,649 [7952795]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.InteropLibraryGen$CachedDispatch.invokeMember(InteropLibraryGen.java:8134)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,649 [7952795]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotValueDispatch$InteropValue$AbstractInvokeNode.executeShared(PolyglotValueDispatch.java:4412)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,649 [7952795]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotValueDispatch$InteropValue$InvokeNode.executeImpl(PolyglotValueDispatch.java:4452)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,649 [7952795]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.HostToGuestRootNode.execute(HostToGuestRootNode.java:125)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,650 [7952796]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.callDirectOrIndirect(DefaultCallTarget.java:85)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,650 [7952796]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultCallTarget.call(DefaultCallTarget.java:102)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,650 [7952796]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultRuntimeAccessor$DefaultRuntimeSupport.callProfiled(DefaultRuntimeAccessor.java:165)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,650 [7952796]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotValueDispatch$InteropValue.invoke(PolyglotValueDispatch.java:2397)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,651 [7952797]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.graalvm.polyglot.Value.invokeMember(Value.java:934)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,651 [7952797]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.MongoShellEvaluator.eval(MongoShellEvaluator.kt:124)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,651 [7952797]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.MongoShell$eval$result$1.invoke(MongoShell.kt:21)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,651 [7952797]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.MongoShell$eval$result$1.invoke(MongoShell.kt:20)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,652 [7952798]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.ConsoleLogSupport.withConsoleLogEnabled(ConsoleLogSupport.kt:28)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,652 [7952798]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -

2022-05-09 13:28:43,652 [7952798]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.mongodb.mongosh.MongoShell.eval(MongoShell.kt:20)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,653 [7952799]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.dbschema.mongo.mongosh.MongoshScriptEngine.execute(MongoshScriptEngine.java:51)

2022-05-09 13:28:43,653 [7952799]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - ... 32 more

2022-05-09 13:29:04,318 [7973464]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Terminating: 127.0.0.1:25464/RemoteDriverImpleb650769

2022-05-09 13:29:04,591 [7973737]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Process finished with exit code -
```

Looking for any other potential work around or fixes for this.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824023/8203759

Comment: Have you tried to connect using your URL via other tools? According to error message - IDE can't connect due to timeout...